# How can I recover an HTML file that's been overwritten by Out-File in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, data-recovery, restore

I accidentally ran

```
PS F:\eycon_work\FrontEnd\CSS Grid>Out-File index.html
```

which removed my code from the PC. I don't have a backup of this file although I have opened it in my web browser before.

How can I get my code back?

This is what it looks like now in my web browser

[image: web page screenshot containing two invalid Unicode symbols]

Comment: Use the `-NoClobber` parameter in the future to prevent the accidental overwriting of a file. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-6

Comment: If File History is turned on, check the file's Properties dialog for Previous Versions.

Comment: Is it possible that this file remains in the browser cache?

Answer (score 2):

Out-file generates a new file. Unless you can restore from a backup, you lost the content of index.html, and the only way to get it back is to recreate it manually (or if you downloaded it, download it again).

Let this be a lesson on how important backups are.

Keep in mind that you can turn on Shadow Copies for your disks, which will allow you to get to an earlier version of a file in the future. By default this is turned off however and will require additional harddrive space as you modify files.

Comment: You *might* have been able to get the cached version if you hadn't opened the new version in your browser.  But it seems that you have, so that's gone too.  At some point in our lives, we've all overwritten or deleted files that we didn't mean to.  Some lessons just need to be learned the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

If the web-page is still displayed in the browser, you may use the Save As command
to get back the file.

If PowerShell deleted the old file in order to write the new one, rather than
just opened the old file and overwritten the existing content,
you may find it in the Recycle Bin.

If none of this is helpful, and you have no backups, then unfortunately it seems
like the file is lost.

Comment: To my knowledge out-file will not move a file to the recycle bin. It will just overwrite it